# call back function with $this

Tags: php

I am trying to use an instance method as a callback for PHP 5.2.1. I am aware that as of PHP 5.4 you can use `$this` inside a closure, and in PHP 5.3 you can rename `$this` to `$self` and pass that to the closure. However, neither of these methods will suffice since I need this to work for PHP 5.2.1. The two commented lines was my last attempt. That results in `Fatal error: Call to a member function hello() on a non-object` - is there anyway I can have a callback to an instance method in PHP 5.2.1?

```
<?php

class Test {

    public function __construct() { 
        $self = &$this;

        $cb = function() use ( $self ) {
            $self->hello();
        };
        call_user_func( $cb );


        // $cb = create_function( '$self', '$self->hello();' );
        // call_user_func( $cb );

    }

    public function hello() {
        echo "Hello, World!\n";
    }
}

$t = new Test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cb = create_function('$self', '$self->hello();');
```

This is just making a function that can take a parameter called `$self`.  It's the same as this:

```
function test($self){
    $self->hello();
}
```

You can try passing `$self` (or `$this`) to the function when you call it:

```
call_user_func($cb, $this);
```

You can also try to make `$self` a global variable, so that the anonymous function made by `create_function` can read it.

```
$GLOBALS['mySelf'] = $self;
$cb = create_function('', 'global $mySelf;  $mySelf->hello();');
call_user_func($cb);
// You may want to unset this when done
unset($GLOBALS['mySelf']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass an array to include the object:

```
call_user_func( array( $this, 'hello' ) );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I should have specified that I can't modify call_user_func in this particular context. Rocket's solution fits exactly.

Answer (score 1):

How about **SIMPLICITY**?

```
class Test {

    public function __construct() { 
        $this -> funcName($this);
    }

    public function funcName($obj) {
            $obj->hello();
    }

    public function hello() {
        echo "Hello, World!\n";
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Just tested the codes. They are working fine using this.

```
call_user_func_array(array($self, "hello"), array());
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity, however this is just a convoluted example of an specific interface I have to adhere to.